# Can I use Databinding for Options menu in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

The following code is from the project architecture-samples, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

I know that I can use such as `viewDataBinding.viewmodel` to access layout control or data.

But in the following code, I find `val view = activity?.findViewById<View>(R.id.menu_filter) ?: return` is appear, it's a traditional code.

Is there a way to access Options menu with `Databinding` or `Viewbinding` technology ？

```
class TasksFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewDataBinding = TasksFragBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return viewDataBinding.root
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) =
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_clear -> {
                viewModel.clearCompletedTasks()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_filter -> {
                showFilteringPopUpMenu()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_refresh -> {
                viewModel.loadTasks(true)
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }


  private fun showFilteringPopUpMenu() {
        val view = activity?.findViewById<View>(R.id.menu_filter) ?: return

        PopupMenu(requireContext(), view).run {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_tasks, menu)

            setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                viewModel.setFiltering(
                    when (it.itemId) {
                        R.id.active -> TasksFilterType.ACTIVE_TASKS
                        R.id.completed -> TasksFilterType.COMPLETED_TASKS
                        else -> TasksFilterType.ALL_TASKS
                    }
                )
                true
            }
            show()
        }
    }

    ...
}


<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat" />

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksViewModel" />

    </data>
    ...
</layout>
```

Comment: Data binding does not support for options menu!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As states in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding):

> View binding is a feature that allows you to more easily write code that interacts with views. Once view binding is enabled in a module, it generates a binding class **for each XML layout file** present in that module. An instance of a binding class contains direct references to all views that have an ID in the corresponding layout.
>
> In most cases, view binding replaces `findViewById`.

Look at the bold words, you notice that View Binding only works for XML layout (located in `res/layout`), whereas the menus are located in `res/menu`.

Also, View Binding uses `findViewById`, whereas menus use `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_id)`, thus it is not possible.